# QGIS--computing local standard deviation (from many bands) to each cell

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have HDF images with 365 bands each. Is there a way to compute local standard deviation across all of these bands with results appearing in each cell?

I have tried Zonal Statistics (with polygons converted from each raster cell as the input vector layer) but it does not appear to work for multiple bands. I also tried using SAGA via QGIS but it gave an error stating multi-band functionality was not supported.

Any one know of a way I can compute this using Raster Calculator or GRASS's r.series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example with an RGB image:

```
r.in.gdal -e -o input=Overview_Tile322.jp2 output=Overview_Tile322
g.region rast=Overview_Tile322
g.list rast
# lists Overview_Tile322.red,Overview_Tile322.green,Overview_Tile322.blue
r.series input=Overview_Tile322.red,Overview_Tile322.green,Overview_Tile322.blue output=Overview_Tile322_stddev method=stddev
```

To make it easier, you may want assign the output of g.mlist to a variable and substitute it into the input of r.series:

```
g.mlist type=rast pattern=Overview_Tile322* separator=,
# prints Overview_Tile322.blue,Overview_Tile322.green,Overview_Tile322.red
```

Comment: There was also a way to do it in raster calculator. _Though it still requires typing in all the band names._  The following is if I was computing the local standard deviation of across 3 bands.   

' First make an image which is the mean of all bands
(("HRAC_V2.3.2014@1"+
"HRAC_V2.3.2014@2"+
"HRAC_V2.3.2014@3")/3) = "MeanImage"  

Then compute the Standard Deviation
√((("HRAC_V2.3.2014@1"-"MeanImage")^2 + ("HRAC_V2.3.2014@2"-"MeanImage")^2 + ("HRAC_V2.3.2014@3"-"MeanImage")^2) / (3-1)) ' 

Thank you 55937!! Using Gdal would likely be easier.